# How to create different length columns for each row in a table using css/js?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

So I have four rows in my table.  I am trying to fill each column with data from a list.  The following is producing table cells from left to right, but i'm trying to populate from up to down.  I'm not sure how to do this with a list though.

```
  <template>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Header 1</td>
      <td>Header 2</td>
      <td>Header 3</td>
      <td>Header 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <template v-for='job in list1'>
      <td>{{ job.id }}</td>
      </template>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <template v-for='job in list2'>
      <td>{{ job.id }}</td>
      </template>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <template v-for='job in list3'>
      <td>{{ job.id }}</td>
    </template>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </template>
```

Comment: create 3 new lists and transpose your data first

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: Transpose: "a matrix formed from another matrix by interchanging the rows and columns" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transpose) I don't know vue.js so this is as much as I can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-process the lists before making the table.  Such as:

```
let preprocessed = [];

for(let i = 0; i < list1.length || i < list2.length || i < list3.length; i++){
    let this_row = [];

    if(list1[i])
        this_row.push(list1[i]);
    else
        this_row.push(null);

    if(list2[i])
        this_row.push(list2[i]);
    else
        this_row.push(null);

    if(list3[i])
        this_row.push(list3[i]);
    else
        this_row.push(null);

    preprocessed.push(this_row);
}
```

Now you have a single list to iterate through, where each element is a list of the elements at that respective index in the original lists.

```
<template>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Header 1</td>
            <td>Header 2</td>
            <td>Header 3</td>
        </tr>    
        <template v-for='elems in preprocessed'>
            <tr>
                <template v-for='elem in elems'>
                    <td v-if="elem !== null">{{ elem.id }}</td>
                    <td v-if="elem === null"></td>
                </template>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </table>
</template>
```

Note:  This is all untested, but should give you an idea..

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to be working for me.  list1, list2, list3 are actually arrays, so not sure if that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: This is for arrays.  the length property is a property of an array - that is not the issue.  You need to give the errors it throws if you want more help.

Comment: Then what is displaying?

Comment: Just the first row with the headers, nothing below that

Comment: Inspect the page to see if any other rows are being produced, but empty.  Otherwise, I have updated my code above which you can try instead.

Comment: there are no other rows being produced

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195373/discussion-between-jaybee-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

By default, HTML tables displays the header to the top and the data from left to right.

To reverse it, you should try something like this

```
<template>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Header 1</td>
        <td v-for="job in list1">{{ job.id }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Header 2</td>
        <td v-for="job in list2">{{ job.id }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Header 3</td>
        <td v-for="job in list3">{{ job.id }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

Comment: This does not do what he wants.  He wants the data in columns.